# all classifiers are predicting "bad" positives

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm classifying my data using several algorithms including

```
KNN, LogisticRegression, RandomForrest, DecisionTreeClassifier, GaussianNB etc.
```

After fitting my data I am analyzing results using the following:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
classification_report(y_test, predicted)
```

Im not totally clear on the semantics of the "predicted positive / negative" et.al in respects to which label it is trying to predict.

Also maybe more importantly I don't understand and am trying to analize why all of the various algorithms are predicting relatively well in regards to "Predicted Negative / True Negative vs Predicted Negative / True Positive" portions but very bad in regards to the "Predict Positive" portion .

In other words from my understanding it is quite good at saying "not something" but basically tossing a coin at predicting "is something" (around 50-50)

here are some example classification reports I generated for the different techniques:

```
confusion matrix (knn)
               Predicted Negative  Predicted Positive
True Negative               14776                5442
True Positive                2367                6337
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          f       0.73      0.86      0.79     17143
          t       0.73      0.54      0.62     11779

avg / total       0.73      0.73      0.72     28922

confusion matrix (SVM)
               Predicted Negative  Predicted Positive
True Negative               14881                4947
True Positive                2262                6832
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          f       0.75      0.87      0.81     17143
          t       0.75      0.58      0.65     11779

avg / total       0.75      0.75      0.74     28922

confusion matrix (logistic regression)
               Predicted Negative  Predicted Positive
True Negative               14881                4947
True Positive                2262                6832
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          f       0.75      0.87      0.81     17143
          t       0.75      0.58      0.65     11779

avg / total       0.75      0.75      0.74     28922

confusion matrix (decision tree)
               Predicted Negative  Predicted Positive
True Negative               14852                4941
True Positive                2291                6838
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          f       0.75      0.87      0.80     17143
          t       0.75      0.58      0.65     11779

avg / total       0.75      0.75      0.74     28922

confusion matrix (naive_bayes)
               Predicted Negative  Predicted Positive
True Negative               13435                4759
True Positive                3708                7020
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          f       0.74      0.78      0.76     17143
          t       0.65      0.60      0.62     11779

avg / total       0.70      0.71      0.70     28922

confusion matrix (random_forest)
               Predicted Negative  Predicted Positive
True Negative               13287                5248
True Positive                3856                6531
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          f       0.72      0.78      0.74     17143
          t       0.63      0.55      0.59     11779

avg / total       0.68      0.69      0.68     28922

confusion matrix (gradient_boost)
               Predicted Negative  Predicted Positive
True Negative               15071                5583
True Positive                2072                6196
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          f       0.73      0.88      0.80     17143
          t       0.75      0.53      0.62     11779

avg / total       0.74      0.74      0.72     28922


confusion matrix (neural network MLPClassifier)
               Predicted Negative  Predicted Positive
True Negative               10789                3653
True Positive                6354                8126
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          f       0.75      0.63      0.68     17143
          t       0.56      0.69      0.62     11779

avg / total       0.67      0.65      0.66     28922
```

The only one which seems to predict "Predicted Positive" reasonably was the MLPClassifier classifier.

Comment: Well that is usually because positives have a more *complex* shape, and thus it is harder for the algorithm to grasp that concept.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't know how the dataset you used looks like. But let's say there is a flipping coin experiment with 2 kinds of results, either head (1) or tail (0). Now we implement a regression algorithm to predict the results based a bunch of possible features.

If the prediction is correct (as same as the class label), we will count it as a true one. If not, it will be a false record.
If the algorithm outputs a "Head" prediction, it would be regarded as a positive result, and negative for "tail".

For single "True Positive" portion, it has a little value. But if we add it with "False Negative", the sum of them is actually the amount of positive case.

And if we divid "True Positive" by the sum of all positive case, which is normally called "recall" or TP rate, we would get the accuracy of this model in predicting positive (head) case.

We could compare the TP rate(TP/P) with the FP rate(FP/N) to analyze the performance of a given model.

There is also some other combination and usage with these positive, negative, true, false and rate things, such as sensitivity and specificity etc..

If you want to know more, I would recommend you to look [ROC Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic)